# Website links won't work with .htaccess code which removes .html extension

Tags: html, .htaccess, web

I have the following code in my .htacess file for my website to remove '.html' from my urls and to redirect any .html to the same page without it (example.com/home.html to example.com/home)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301] 

#301 from example.com/page.html to example.com/page
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

However, when I try to click on links that are pointed to other pages on my website, I get a 404 error.
I've tried setting the href to http://www.example.com/page2, /page2 and more but I still get the same error. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Please save your code and put only the following code in your main directory `.htaccess` file :

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(.*?)\.html[\s?/] [NC]
  RewriteRule  (.*)$  /%1%2 [R=302,L,NE]
```

**Note:** clear your browser cache because you did `301` redirect and test the code

Comment: I changed it and it didn't do anything

Comment: Yes, i did. Still did nothing. I'm able to access multiple pages on my primary domain, but I can't access any on the secondary domain

Comment: it works fine for me , ok you have another browser right? if you check by chrome use IE i meant change the browser ,